# cant resolve my site url net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, resolve

i cant resolve my site
and in console i got this error

> http://https//www.madmind.ir/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

why my address have http and https both ?
i active my ssl cetificate and got this error

**vhost panel : Plesk**
**frame work : mvc 5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect is misconfigured:

```
$ curl -v madmind.ir
...
> Connected to madmind.ir (95.38.61.126) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: madmind.ir
...
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: http://https://www.madmind.ir/
```

Notice the  **http://https://**

Also, your certificate is self signed, that will cause something like:

```
www.madmind.ir uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. 
The certificate is not valid for the name www.madmind.ir. 
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

Comment: how i can fix this ?any idea ?
@Dusan Bajic

Comment: Find a place where this redirect is configured (in IIS probably) and examine the configuration (or paste here).